# How to get the height of a DIV considering inner element's margins?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider de following markup:

```
<div id="outerElement">
    <div id="innerElement" style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #f0f3f5; margin-top: 100px">  
        TESTE
    </div>
</div>
```

**I want to get the actual final height of `outerElement` using javascript**. I noticed that if I remove the vertical margins from `innerElement` I am able to get what I want but I cannot alter styles from within the `outerElement`.

**How do I do this?**

Obs:
I already tried height, scrollheight and offsetHeight in all browsers. Chrome gives me the expected value (including inner element's margins) for `scrollHeight`. All other browsers fail.

Comment: None of the answers down (as of december 2011) makes sense, I wonder if you found a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

If you can set the outer div to style `display : inline-block;` then `scrollHeight` will include the margins of child elements.

It will also work if you set style `display : flex;` (supported by IE 9+)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use jQuery. Try using

```
$("#myelementId").height()
```

And see if that does it.

Comment: not related to question at all! Why to load jQuery only for finding height for an element?

Comment: Use jQuery seems like a pretty solid suggestion. Not my favorite, but valid. +1

Answer (score 1):

Add clearfix, use jquery height() and remove the clearfix class again.

That's gonna work. : )

Comment: Adding the clearfix actually did it. The simplest solution is to temporarily add `overflow: hidden` to the outer element, calculate the size and then remove it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `clientHeight`

```
var outerElement = document.getElementById("outerElement");
if(outerElement.clientHeight) {
alert("Height is "+outerElement.clientHeight+"px");
}
else { alert("Old browser?"); }
```

I know what you're thinking... "this won't work!" and alas, it doesn't... but if you do something like add a border to `outerElement`... even for just a moment...

```
var outerElement = document.getElementById("outerElement");
outerElement.style.border = "1px solid black";
var height = outerElement.clientHeight;
outerElement.style.border = "none";
alert("Height is "+height+"px");
```

Not the most beautiful solution but it works, and if you can figure out *why* it works (I sure as hell don't know :P) you might be closer to a *good* solution...

Some older browsers may not support it though... you'd have to look into it; I can't list 'em.

Answer (score 0):

you could use jQuery:

```
$('#outerElement').height(); // gets the height of the div
$('#outerElement').outerHeight(); // gets the height of the div including margins and padding
$('#outerElement').innerHeight(); // gets the height of the div including padding
```

one of those is bound to work.

Comment: not related to question at all! Why to load jQuery only for finding height for an element?

Comment: Now wait a minute, the user asked for the best way to get the height of an element. He also mentioned that his current solution only works in certain browsers. What chadley and I are presenting here is a way to retrieve his information and solve his problem. I don't see what the problem is if our solution happens to involve implmenting the use of a JS library like jQuery. If it's a possible solution, why not present it?

Comment: this is definitely related to the question. he asked how to do it and i told him how he can, with jQuery. you don't even know its not being loaded already. i'd say most websites built today include some kind of js framework.

@andre: i think the problem is that the margin pushes down the #outerElement as well so the actual height of #outerElement is the same as the #innerElement. do you understand what i mean?

Comment: I agree Levi! However, this suggests several methods, with no assurance that they are not just wrappers for the techniques he tried already... it feels like less of an answer and more of a carpet bomb jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

ok also not pretty but this is how I do it (disclaimer: I stole this from somewhere once)

```
var height = elem.clientHeight + getBufferHeight(elem, true);

function getBufferHeight(elem, includeMargins) {
    if (!elem.visible()) {
        return 0;
    }
    //do new Number instead of parseFloat to avoid rounding errors 
    var result = 0;
    if (includeMargins) {
        result =   
            new Number(elem.getStyle('marginTop').replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '')).ceil() +  
            new Number(elem.getStyle('marginBottom').replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '')).ceil();
    }     
    result +=
        new Number(elem.getStyle('borderBottomWidth').replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '')).ceil() +
        new Number(elem.getStyle('borderTopWidth').replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '')).ceil() +    
        new Number(elem.getStyle('paddingTop').replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '')).ceil() +
        new Number(elem.getStyle('paddingBottom').replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '')).ceil();                        
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question as what do you discern as the "appropriate" height. The height of the content inside including borders, what about padding, or the actual margin use? In general browser act fairly consistent on most things, but [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#elementview) can clear up what you need. (As a hint, if you need the actual margin used, its gonna hurt).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should go throw all element properties and the make a sum only in this way you can know the exactly height... but in the case of the height is set it by for example clear:both property I dont think is posible to know the heigth of an Element.

A 3 sec thought could be something like:

var o document.getElementById('id').style;

```
    var total = ((o.height.split("px")[0] == "") ? 0 : o.height.split("px")[0]) +
 ((o.marginTop.split("px")[0] == "") ? 0 : o.marginTop.split("px")[0]) + 
((o.marginBottom.split("px")[0] == "") ? 0 : o.marginBottom.split("px")[0]) + 
((o.paddingTop.split("px")[0] == "") ? 0 : o.paddingTop.split("px")[0]) +
    ((o.borderTop.split("px")[0] == "") ? 0 : o.borderTop.split("px")[0]) +
 ((o.borderBottom.split("px")[0] == "") ? 0 : o.borderBottom.split("px")[0])
```

But I guess you must include also the document.getElementById('id').height value if have it.... is thougth but can help..

best =)

Answer (score 0):

WARNING WARNING `clientHeight` almost works but doesn't include margins :(

Just thought I'd add that I've been trying this today, and while nahumsilva & plodder almost have it right (nahumsilva's version appears to be more cross-browser {plodder's doesn't appear to work in Chrome/WebKit, but I'm no expert on these things}), they've both missed that an element may have computed style elements that aren't defined by it's own style.

This was driving me nuts - I was wondering where my `<p>` elements were getting an extra 16px of margin height - until I realised it was coming from the computed style.

So, long story short, an approach like nahumsilva / plodder worked for me, with the added proviso that you should get the element's computed style with `window.getComputedStyle( element, null )`, which returns a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object (like `element.style`). `element.offsetHeight` / `element.clientHeight` should give you the height without margins, so the whole thing looks like:

```
var cstyle = window.getComputedStyle( element, null );
var elementHeight = element.offsetHeight +
Number( cstyle.marginBottom.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '') ) +
Number( cstyle.marginTop.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '') );
```

Answer (score 0):

try [$("#myelementId").outerHeight( true )](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

Answer (score -3):

This answer may be a little obvious, but if you already know the margin, why not just manually add it to the height?