# Use JS to Calculate Div Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using some javascript to calculate the height of the page and then set a min-height on on a div. The reason for this is to push the footer to the bottom of the page for pages that are short on content. My issue is the min-height is about 30-40 px to big thus causing scroll bars. (Note: I am not using a solution like sticky footer for various reasons and prefer this solution.)

Here is my code:

***JS***

```
$(function() {
  var height = $(window).height() - ($("header").outerHeight() + $("footer").outerHeight() );
 $("#page-content").css("min-height",height+"px");
});
```

***HTML***

```
 <header class="container">
 <div id="menu" class="row">
   <!-- Content -->
 </div>
</header>

<div id="page-content">
  <!-- Content --> 
</div>

<footer>
  <!-- Content --> 
</footer>
```

I believe the issue lies in my CSS. For example I have a margin in the header as so:

```
#menu{
 margin: 5px auto 10px;
}
```

If I remove that code it will reduce the scrollbar just a little bit. (I have other margins set in place on the page so changing just this one will not work as a solution).

How would I re-write the JS code to factor in the margin for the header and other sections?

Comment: why not calculate if the window is short on content, then set the `position` of the footer to fixed/bottom?

Comment: I've got a similar issue but in width, about 8px offset very strange.

Comment: You are already using .outerHeight() which takes in account for margins and padding... on a side note, I would write this line like this $("#page-content").css({ "min-height": height });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the JS is not calculating the margins. I added the margins I had in the header and footer and they totaled 45px.  Thus the script now looks like so:

```
$(function() {
  var height = $(window).height() - ($("header").outerHeight() + 
               $("footer").outerHeight() + 45   ); 
  $("#page-content").css("min-height",height+"px"); 
});
```

I add 45px and the script now functions correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The `<header>` box's height doesn't reflect the child `#menu`'s margins because they are both normal box elements, and if the `#page-content` had margins, they would overlap the `#menu`'s margins, in which case the header's height would include some part of the content's height, which wouldn't make sense.

The issue is collapsing margins: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins

As that page explains, you can get tell the browser not to collapse margins a few ways:

- add `display: inline-block;` to your `#menu { }` rules (my first suggestion)
- add `overflow: hidden;` to your `header { }` (a potentially better suggestion if you're having alignment issues)
- make your `<header>` absolutely positioned, or float it. Or do that to the `#menu` inside.

Or if you want to go for a hack, you could calculate the header height manually:

```
var header_height = $("header").outerHeight() +
   parseInt($("header").children().css('margin-top'), 10) +
   parseInt($("header").children().css('margin-bottom'), 10);
```

Now that I think about it, this makes sense, and I think the css spec is doing the right thing.

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/HzBSz/2/

Also see: [Outer element margin not equal to inner element margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431434/outer-element-margin-not-equal-to-inner-element-margin)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just place the footer on the bottom manually? I mean, I know you said you prefer not to, but why? If you want it to always be there, do

```
position:relative;
bottom:0;
```

If you want it to scroll with the rest of the page (as it sounds like you may), use

```
position:absolute;
```

instead.
This is a much better method than dynamically inserting dummy content to push a footer down.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you look at this
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page
may solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You are encouraged to post a more substantial answer rather than simply a link, especially in cases like this where there is a specific question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

**Try .outerHeight(true) for all your elements instead of .height() or .outerHeight():**

```
$(function() {
  var height = $(window).outerHeight(true) - ($("header").outerHeight(true) + $("footer").outerHeight(true) );
 $("#page-content").css("min-height",height+"px");
});
```

.height() - returns the height of element excludes padding, border and margin.

.innerHeight() - returns the height of element includes padding but excludes border and margin.

.outerHeight() - returns the height of the div including border but excludes margin.

.outerHeight(true) - returns the height of the div including margin.

Comment: .outerWidth( true ); // Returns the width + padding + borders + margins